# My laptop not charging after 60%

Tags: system, battery

Recently i installed freya.
my laptop (Lenovo G50-80) is not charging after 60%. Then i installed windows But in windows working fine without any power management s/w. 
Then i again install freya (fresh install) But the problem still same.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the battery is crystallized or being damaged.
I have seen that even Windows is not able to recognize the current state of a battery, in exchange gnu Linux recognizes when a battery is being damaged by statistics and charts showing the current state of the battery since it was installed ElementaryOS

Comment: i found solution for this problem.
Hardware vendors ship their Li-ion battery with battery firmware.So this is controlled by power management utility. If we usages our laptop with AC adaptor all time. Then battery threshold automatically set to 60% to prevent damage or over charge condition.
Battery firmware is only controlled by the power management utility.
For more Details you can read from here
[Battery threshold problem solution](http://www.techsarjan.com/2016/03/my-laptop-battery-not-charging-after-60-solved.html)